# Why don't VTT subtitles work in KM Player?

Tags: video, subtitles, kmplayer

I'm using KM player to play some videos from my downloaded Udemy courses. These videos are coupled with VTT subtitles.

Since the .mp4 and .vtt files have the same name, I'm supposed to see my videos with subtitles. But nothing showed in the bottom of the videos.

I followed some advice on Youtube and tried converting the .vtt file into .srt format (including removal of the beginning "WEBVTT line and replacement of "." with ",". Still, nothing changed.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks.

P/s: It happened regardless of the tool I used for playing videos, being KMplayer, VLC or MPC.

Answer (score 4):

This might be an old question, but this answer may save other users time :

First you might want to convert the subtitle from WebVTT (.vtt) format to Subrip (SRT) format. The Subrip format is more widely supported by media players, especially KMPlayer (which doesn't support vtt format by default).

You can use **Subtitle Edit** (https://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit or https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) to do the converting jobs. This software is completely free and open-source.

For your convenient, you might want to do batch converting a lot of subtitles. In order to do so, you might want to use **Batch Convert**.
Batch convert is accessible via **Tools -> Batch** convert...

[Batch Converting process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K90le.png)

You might also want to **Save in source file folder** so that you don't have to move the subtitle after converting.

After that, use KMPlayer to play the video. It should have subtitle now. If it don't, you may try adding the subtitles manually in KMPlayer by clicking **Menu -> Subtitles -> Load Subtitles** or just **Alt + O**.

If all of that doesn't work, you may want to checking out if the subtitle is disabled. To do so, click the **Subtitle icon** at lower right of KMPlayer (as shown in below image) :
[Subtitle Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKxwe.png)

Make sure **Enable** is checked.
[Enable menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eexYe.png)